# Connection string for Oracle ORDS docker container

Tags: oracle, docker, containers

`Cannot connect to database please validate CONN_STRING has below shape: user/password@hostname:port/service_name`

my connection string: CONN_STRING=sys/#mypwd#@172.xx.0.xx:1521/ORCLCDB

My oracle-db container is up and running, can connect to it in SQL Developer (user and pwd are ok, service_name and port are ok).

Anything else I can try?

Both oracle-db container and ords container are set to run in the same docker network (so network ok) I tried with the container ip (the one 170.xx.0.xx like from) as hostname, no luck.

Comment: `SYS` can only connect using the `AS SYSDBA` modifier, and should **NEVER** be used for application connections like ORDS. Connecting as `SYS` without the `AS SYSDBA` modifier will result in an error every time.

Comment: Thanks, now my connection string works

CONN_STRING="sys as sysdba/#mypwd#@172.xx.0.xx:1521/ORCLCDB" (any other quotes combo didnt work).

ORDS' container runs now and installs ORDS instance and APEX over the target oracle-db container.

While the log file states:

INFO : APEX has been installed.

INFO : Configuring APEX.

INFO : APEX_PUBLIC_USER has been configured as oracle.

I cant find any trace of APEX in the dba_registry

I can see the ords instance in http://myhostt:8181/ords/ but APEX login is not showing up (ORDS 404 instead with some errors I'm about to check out)